# Force touch Home Screen Quick Actions to use app in folder without notifications? (IOS)

Tags: iphone, ios

I just discovered that I can check apps with notifications with force touch on a folder. Is there a way to enable force touch for ALL apps in a folder, not just those with notifications?

This would be SUCH a useful feature. It would basically allow me to put all apps on one screen and access them with quick gestures. I hate having to move to the middle of the screen to access apps in a folder, so clunky. Makes quick access non-viable.

If not, is there a quicker way to access apps in folders than going to the middle of the screen?